# SwiftUI-How to do animate image for some time-interval in swfitUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I want to animate/transform my image by scaling, rotating with alpha variation in swiftUI. I want an animation for 5 seconds and after that, I should navigate t another view. Any help would be appreciated.